# Joining elements of nested lists in Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a nested list `str` that looks like below:

```
[["22","ABC","XYZ"],["555","IJK","PQR"],...]
```

I have to combine the elements of the inside list with a `/` then join them with a `,` to form a string as:

```
22/ABC/XYZ,555/IJK/PQR,...
```

I tried with `set_fact` and jinja2 but no luck.

```
- set_fact:
     str1: |-
       {%- set fs = "" -%}
       {%- set im = "" -%}
       {%- for i in str -%}
         {%- for elem in i -%}
           {%- set im = im + "/" + elem -%}
         {%- endfor -%}
         {%- set fs = fs + "," + im -%}
       {%- endfor -%}
       {{ fs }}
- debug: var=str1
```

Output:

```
TASK [debug var=str1] **********************************
ok: [host1] => {
    "str1": ""
```

Expected output:

```
TASK [debug var=str1] **********************************
ok: [host1] => {
    "str1": "22/ABC/XYZ,555/IJK/PQR"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First *map* the filter *join(/)* to the items of the list and then *join(,)* them

```yaml
  - set_fact:
      str1: "{{ str|map('join', '/')|join(',') }}"
  - debug: var=str1
```

gives

```yaml
  str1: 22/ABC/XYZ,555/IJK/PQR
```

Comment: So short and works like a charm! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `wiht_list` to create a var with a list with items joined with `/` and later join it with `,`.

```yaml
  - set_fact:
      str1: "{{ str1 | default([]) + [ item | join('/') ] }}"
    with_list: "{{ str }}"

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ str1 | join(',') }}"
```